# Any way to bundle MySQL with electron app

Tags: javascript, mysql, electron, electron-packager

I'm new to electron, creating an electron app that uses mysql database. I'm using `electron-packager` to build the packages for windows OS. I wanna bundle mysql with my app, so a user doesn't need to install mysql separately. Any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you *really* need it, I would consider using an embedded db like SQLite instead.  There are quite a few tutorials on how to use it with electron and will be a lot smaller footprint for your users.

Comment: @StevenB., is there a reason? Is the issue that the user can have a running instance so that there is a conflict? Can it be like LAMP AND XAMP which comes with a local mysql location to use in the webapp? Can the performance of sqlite compare to mysql?